# Do network tags work across peered VPCs on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have two VPCs peered on gcp, `management` and `production`. I gave the network tag `bastion` to my bastion vm inside the `management` vpc, and then made a firewall rule inside `production` to allow SSH traffic from anything tagged `bastion`. However `production` is not allowing ssh traffic from `management` with that network tag.

Unless I have something misconfigured, network tags *do not* seem to be working across peered VPCs. I've instead created a firewall rule inside `production` to allow the iprange of the `management` vpc, and that works, but I can't seem to do it with network tags.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, firewall tags are not propagated accross peering VPC networks. We are working on the feature, no ETA is available.

In the meantime, would using [Static Internal IPs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-internal-ip-address) for the bastion VMs help?

Comment: could you send a link to the issue you are referring to?